# how to invoke edge browser using new Selenium service method with golang

Tags: selenium, go

I want to be able to automate my tests using Microsoft Edge browser using Selenium GoDog framework. Can someone please provide suggestions on how to invoke edge browser using new Selenium service method and how to set up the capabilities and service option?

Cannot find service method for edge we have chrome only

Comment: Maybe https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/ is a better choice. Note: I'm one of the maintainers of https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp.